# Git merge does not add new files

Tags: git, merge

Here's my commit history:

```
 * Merge commit (missing file a.c)
/|
||
*| Add new file a.c again <- branchB
||
|* Remove files a.c <- branchA
||
*| Remove files a.c
||
\|
 |
 * Add new file a.c
 |
 |
...
```

I have a branchA branch where I added a file. Then, I branched to branchB. For some reason (refactoring), the file was later deleted in branchB. I backported those changes into branchA. But again later, I added the file in branchB. Finally I merged branchB into branchA.

```
git checkout branchA
git merge branchB
```

During the merge, there's no mention of file a.c. And the file does not exist after the merge in branchA. Why is git not able to see that in branchB the file a.c was added AFTER (with respect to date and time) the deletion (in both branches) and thus it need to keep it? At least, I would like to see a conflict or something...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the git commands you ran?

Comment: I edited my post. Simply using git checkout then git merge. Of course, I have a lot more commits in both branches and had to resolve some conflicts. But there was no conflict related to this file.

Comment: It shouldn't look at the dates, as merges aren't meant to prefer later changes than earlier.

Comment: Dates-and-times are irrelevant to Git; what matters are *commits*.  Specifically, three—and *only* three—commits matter: the *merge base*, where the two branches come back together (that's your bottom `Add new file a.c` commit), and the two *branch tips* A and B. Git diffs the merge base against A to see what group A changed. Git diffs the merge base against B to see what group B changed. Git then combines the two changes, applies the combined changes to the merge base, and commits the result.

Comment: Ok, so Git sees that there's no change for file a.c between the merge base and branchB. But between the merge base and branchA it sees a deletion. So the result is that the file a.c is deleted.

In my case, using git merge, even after managing conflicts, the resulting project is in an invalid state and are not able to compile/work anymore... From a git point of view, what should I do? Is there an alternative to git merge or a merge parameter that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Specifically, three—and only three—commits matter: the merge base,
>   where the two branches come back together (that's your bottom Add new
>   file a.c commit), and the two branch tips A and B.

And, as you mentioned:

> Git sees that there's no change for file a.c between the merge base
>   and branchB. But between the merge base and branchA it sees a
>   deletion. So the result is that the file a.c is deleted.

You can use `git difftool` on the two commits right before you merged branches.  You will be able to see the missing files and their contents, and manually resave them.

You can also use `git diff --name-only` on the two branches.  Once you have identified the missing files, you can directly check them out from branchB into branchA:

```
git checkout branchA
git checkout branchB -- a.c
```